# Close Python Websocket server from another thread

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I have a websocket server class that has a `stop()` method that is called when Control+C is pressed in console (so I guess **it is accessed from another thread**).

How can I safely stop the server (and finish the script from running) when `stop()` is called?

Current implementation executes `stop()` method, but the script keeps running and does not print `Server closed`. But if a client sends a message after the `stop()` method is called, then the scripts actually finished and prints `Server closed` message.

```
import asyncio
import websockets

DOMAIN = 'localhost'
PORT = 1111

class EchoServer:
    loop = None

    def stop(self): # METHOD CALLED FROM ANOTHER THREAD
        self.loop.stop()

    def process_message(self, message):
        print(message)
        return message

    async def handle(self, ws_client):
        print('Listening')
        async for message in ws_client:
            await ws_client.send(message)

    async def main(self):
        start_server = websockets.serve(self.handle, DOMAIN, PORT)
        asyncio.ensure_future(start_server)

    def start(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.loop.create_task(self.main())
        print('Starting server...')
        self.loop.run_forever()

        print('Server closed')
```

Answer (score 1):

Although calling `loop.stop` will eventually stop it - if the `stop` method is executed in the loop own event scheduling, it is immediate.

That can be done with the method `call_soon_threadsafe` from the loop itself: it will schedule the `stop` method as a task to be called by the loop itself. This call can be done from your controler thread with no problems.

So just change your stop method to:

```
    def stop(self): # METHOD CALLED FROM ANOTHER THREAD
        self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.loop.stop)
```

Comment: Thanks. Similar to ChatGPT solution I posted. Just a question, which implementation do you think is better? Just change this on stop method, or the one I posted.

Comment: the one you posted uses the same idea  - a proper call inserted in the event loop, but to stop the socketserver, instead of the asyncio loop: that will cause it to shut down in a more proper way.  Also, moving the code around loop start/stop to the chjild thread is not bad. The only things are that if you are not using `.is_running`  in your class, just drop that line, and, the GPT code won't print "server started" until after the server stops.  :-) (I will comment on the other answer how to fix that)

Comment: oh, sorry,I overlooked it - the awaited call jut starts the server, it is not meant to wait for the server to shut-down. So it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

After some chit chat with our friend ChatGPT. I came to a solution:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

DOMAIN = 'localhost'
PORT = 1111

class EchoServer:
    loop = None

    def stop(self): # METHOD CALLED FROM ANOTHER THREAD
        self.isrunning = False
        if self.server:
            self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.stop_event.set)
            self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.server.close)
        else:
            print('Server closed')

    def process_message(self, message):
        print(message)
        return message

    async def handle(self, ws_client):
        print('Listening')
        async for message in ws_client:
            await ws_client.send(message)

    async def main(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        self.stop_event = asyncio.Event()
        self.server = await websockets.serve(self.handle, DOMAIN, PORT)
        print('Server started')
        await self.stop_event.wait()
        print('Server stop')

    def start(self):
        asyncio.run(self.main())
        print('Server closed')
```